# Clear and re populate drop down list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to set an alert every time this option (valList4) is clicked as well as automatically filling in the next text box. I want this to work even if after the first choice, another choice will still work.

I have this code:

```
$("#List4").change(function() {

                var valList4 = $("#List4").val();

                if (valList4 == "Ferrari")

                {

                    $("#List5")[0].selectedIndex = 1;

                    fillSelect($("#List4").val(),$("#List5")[0]);

                }



                else if (valList4 == "Porsche")

                {

                    $("#List5")[0].selectedIndex = 1;

                    fillSelect($("#List4").val(),$("#List5")[0]);

                }
```

Here is the alert at the end of the code:

```
alert("Your selection was:- \n" + valList4);

                });
```

The problem is that if I change my selection from one to the other, the list keeps populating and the second box will not change with the first box.

**EDIT**

Fill Select function

```
function fillSelect(currCat,currList){

                var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));

                for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {

                document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;

                document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;



            }
```

HTML Code

```
<form name="completion" action="">

<select id='List4' name='List4' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List5'])">

<option selected>Make a selection</option>

</select>

&nbsp;

<select id='List5' name='List5' onchange="getValue2(this.value, this.form['List4'].value, 

this.form['List4'].value)">

<option selected >Make a selection</option>

</select></P>

</form>
```

Comment: What does fillSelect look like?

Comment: Can you show fillSelect function code? also some html could help!

Comment: Sorry I have added the extra info, thank you for replying